# How to customize AWS DynamoDB stream shards

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to run concurrent lambda functions (multiple functions running at same time) which get triggered by DynamoDB stream.
From my understanding, to run concurrent tasks there should be multiple shards created in DynamoDB stream so that from each shard, one function get executed. Refer [this link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) .
I think currently I am getting one shard for all records that are inserted in DynamoDB at same time. Can anyone help me.
Thank you.

Comment: It has been asked before. Currently AWS says that at most 2 listeners for the stream otherwise you can experience throttling. And it is not possible to control the shards in the stream yourself.
Could it be a solution to have 1/2 functions triggered by the stream and then route the stream items async to other functions by calling them from the 1 or 2 route functions?

Comment: Hey, thank you for the instant reply. I have a use case where I need exactly 1 stream record to be read by lambda and I am inserting 100 + records at same time in DynamoDB. So I thought by customizing stream shard, I can run single lambda function with concurrent executions.  If we cannot control DynamoDB stream shard, is there any way to improve its optimization then?